# Book of exercises on sequences and/or series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a dedicated problem/exercise book or pdf to work on limits of sequences and/or convergence of series (real analysis). Something like 1000 exercises with or without solution depending on the difficulty. A new year resolution of mine is studying one a day.

Comment: Have a look at http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~icstmkw/ma2930/anma2930.pdf

Comment: Thank you @ThomasL, I'll give it a look.

Comment: Hardcore level : real numbers-sequences-series by Kaczor-Nowak

Answer (score 2):

- Problems in Mathematical Analysis I: Real Numbers, Sequences and Series
- Problems in Real Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis by Teodora-Liliana Radulescu, Titu Andreescu, and Vicentiu Radulescu
- Knopp's Theory and Applications of Infinite Series
- Infinite Series by Earl David Rainville
- Bonar and Khoury's Real Infinite Series
- An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series by Thomas John I'Anson Bromwich

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below references:

[A Problem Book in Real Analysis](http://facultymembers.sbu.ac.ir/shahrokhi/ProBookMathAnal1.pdf) by Asuman G. Aksoy & Mohamed A. Khamsi
[Advanced Calculus](https://www.amazon.in/Schaums-Outline-Advanced-Calculus-Outlines/dp/0071623663) by Robert Wrede, Murray Spiegel 
[Methods of Solving Sequence and Series Problems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319456850) by  Ellina Grigorieva
[Sequences and Series](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eazoff/courses/3100sp10.pdf) by Edward A. Azof

All the above mentioned books contains various problems with solutions (not all). I think these will help you a lot.